# How do I restore the .bashrc file if I delete it unfortunately?

Tags: bash, macos

[image]

What if I delete the .bashrc file unfortunately on OSX and I can't use Terminal now? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah solved.
Just because I changed the the source ~/.bashrc into source ~/.bash_profile in .bash_profile file. I changed it back and it works.